# how to deploy a struts2 web application in tomcat? without eclipse? How I should arrange the files in folder?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, deployment, struts2, tomcat7

How can i deploy a struts2 web application in tomcat? I want to avoid eclipse from deploying enviorment. How should I arrange the files in project  folder?

I downloaded 'Struts2' from Apache struts site, but I don't know how to use them.

My project was created with Eclipse IDE and i am using MySql database and Tomcat server. It can be successfully deployed from that environment. I don't want to use Eclipse IDE in my deployment.

Is there any change in arrangement of files needed when I place my project in
`webapps->root folder` of tomcat. 
If so, please give me the order required.

I downloaded some examples from Apache site and they run if I deploy them from eclipse, but when I place them in tomcat root folder and run, it shows struts2 tags not found..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way was exporting the project into a . war file.

Copy it into webapps of tomcat server.

Run tomcat

then it will be loaded

Comment: while creating the war file there is an option to add or not to add java files..
Using that option code security can be achived..

Comment: Class files will be added in war files, which will work insted of java files

Comment: The project file configuration in work space is different in eclipse, so by directly copying project from there to tomcat will not work, but the exported war file will work..

Comment: this approach is only good until unless you are deploying on your local machine:)

Answer (score 1):

You have many option for this the best in my opinion is to avoid creating a manual structure for the deployment and let the tools handle this.

best tool for deployment will be 
[Apache maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

all you need to tell maven about your deployment preferences like you want it to war/jar or any other form

Maven will handle all the other details for you.

else download sample application war from Apache strust2 website deploy that war in the tomcat, tomcat will extract the war in to standard directory structure which can always help you to understand the layout.

My bet is to go for maven as its very easy and handy tool for all these processes.

Comment: @sarinjacob it better to mark answer as approved when it able to solve your issue.approved answer will get less visibility as compare to open question which means you can skip some potential inputs from other members :).

Comment: Is that means if I mark an answer as approved, then chance for getting more response for my question will reduce?

Comment: thats true since when they flash on the SO page approved answer have different colors which show other community members that the problem has already been resolved so some of them can skip question.

Comment: I downloaded the maven, How can I use it?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html   http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html

Answer (score 0):

*What* did you download? Have you written an app yet? Have you gone through any S2 tutorials or sample projects?

An S2 app follows the same directory layout as any web app, plus a few things related specifically to Struts 2. The S2 demo sample app `war` files can be dropped into Tomcat's `webapps` folder and they'll be deployed accordingly.

The struts2-blank application shows the directory layout of an S2 application, and there is a Maven archetype available as well.

Maven is useful for building applications, but is not necessary for deployment (and you'll need the tomcat plugin to deploy anyway). You can also use Maven to test the app without deploying it to Tomcat (using Jetty).

Comment: I have prepared a project in struts2 format using eclipse+tomcat6+MySql. It is working fine also. What I am trying to achive is run my project directly in tomcat without the help of eclipse. Also I would like to know about how to run a .war file from tomcat

Comment: I tried to run my project from tomcat by copying my project in root folder in webApps of tomcat. All the other normal jsp projects are successfully deployed, but struts2 project is not loaded. I think there is some difforence in configuration of struts 2 projects in eclipse and netbeans, etc.

Comment: @sarinjacob You should either deploy a war file, or create the correct directory structure: compiled classes in `WEB-INF/classes`, required libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`, S2 config files on the classpath under `WEB-INF/classes`, `web.xml` in `WEB-INF`, etc. There is nothing unusual about an S2 webapp's directory structure--all web apps use the same, standard structure.

Comment: @sarinjacob if your intentions are to understand how struts2 application layout looks like in deployment environment best approach as Dave has also suggested is to download the sample application from struts2 official site and study that